# Auto fill Combo Boxs with data from SQL server database VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

l have a data source that contains two columns

```
block_name        total_lands
   A-0                 5
   A-1                 15
   A-2                 18
   A-3                 18
```

And I have two combo boxes one for the block name and the other for the no of lands
the first one is loaded with the block names

```
Private Sub LoadItems()

        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT block_name FROM blocks;")


        For Each i As DataRow In SQL.DBDTable.Rows
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(i("block_name"))
        Next

    End Sub
```

I want the second one to be loaded with numbers from 1 to whatever is in the data source row `total_lands`

For example if the user chose the block name as `A-1` I want the second combo box to have the items from 1 to 15 add in it

My code trying to do so

```
Private Sub LoadNoOfLands()
        SQL.AddParam("@blockname", ComboBox1.Text)

        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT totla_lands FROM blocks WHERE total_lands LIKE @blockname;")

        For Each no As DataRow In SQL.DBDTable.Rows
            Dim lands As Integer = no("block_lands")
            'For Each i As Integer In lands
            '
            '
            'Next 

        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: So whats the problem/question?

Comment: I could not add the items to the second combobox
I want the second one to be loaded with numbers from 1 to whatever is in the data source row "total_land"

Comment: So you don't appear to have any code in that method, how is it different to your first combobox load? Please [edit] your question such that you are actually asking for assistance.

Comment: I have tryed to explain and gave an example also please read the example, as the second combobox will have just one item form the data source which is number and i want to have items from 1 to that last number form example the items will be:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,.....,15

Comment: Might want to look at data binding at least your first combo, that will simplify retrieving the required block_lands to filter the query for your 2nd combo

Answer (score 0):

Load required data at once and use `Enumerator.Range` to generate collection of numbers for second combobox

```vb
Public Class Block
  Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
  Public ReadOnly Property TotalLands As Integer
  Public ReadOnly Property Lands As Integer()

  Public Sub New(name As String, totalLands As Intger)
    Name = name
    TotalLands = totalLands
    Lands = Enumerable.Range(1, totalLands).ToArray()
  End Sub
End Class

Private Function LoadBlocks() As Block()
  Dim query = "SELECT block_name, total_lands FROM table"
  Dim rows = SQL.ExecuteQuery(query)

  Return rows.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(row) New Block(row.Field(Of String)("block_name"), row.Field(Of Integer)("total_lands"))).
    ToArray()
End Function

Private Sub SetupComboBox()
  cmbBlocks.DisplayMemeber = "Name"     
  cmbBlocks.DataSource = LoadBlocks()
End Sub

Private Sub cmbBlocks_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbBlocks.SelectionChangeCommitted
  Dim combobox As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
  Dim block As Block = DirectCast(combobox.SelectedValue, Block)

  cmbLands.DataSource = block.Lands
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a simple answer

```
Private Sub LoadNoOfLands()
    cmbLands.Items.Clear()
    SQL.AddParam("@blockname", cmbBlocks.Text)

    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT total_lands FROM blocks WHERE block_name LIKE @blockname;")

    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub

    For Each i As DataRow In SQL.DBDTable.Rows
        Dim lands = i("total_lands")
        Dim r = 1
        For r = 1 To lands
            cmbLands.Items.Add(r).ToString()
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

This function just adds number to combobox form 1 to the total_lands value

Comment: This requires a second call to the database; usually not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class for the data.

```
Public Class Block
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property TotalLands As Integer
    Public Sub New(BlockName As String, Lands As Integer)
        Name = BlockName
        TotalLands = Lands
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

The combo box will call `.ToString` on the items to determine what to display.

We get the data from the database and add it to the `List(Of Block)`

```
Public Function FillBlocksList() As List(Of Block)
    Dim lst As New List(Of Block)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select block_name, total_lands From BlockTable;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Do While reader.Read
                Dim b As New Block(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1))
                lst.Add(b)
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
    Return lst
End Function
```

To fill the first combo we get the list then loop through it adding the `Block` objects to the combo. You would probably call this from `Form.Load`.

```
Public Sub FillBlocksCombo()
    Dim lst = FillBlocksList()
    For Each item In lst
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

To fill the second combo cast the select item back its underlying type, `Block` and use the `TotalLands` property to add the numbers.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim NumberOfLands = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Block).TotalLands
    For i = 1 To NumberOfLands
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(i.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```